# How to replace empty strings in a dataframe with NA (missing value) not NA string

Tags: r, xlsx, xls

I have a titanic xlsx file, which has a lot of blank or empty cells and I saved the file as csv and all the blanks were saved as it is.

When I import the csv file I see a lot of empty strings/blanks in the dataset, one such column is **boat**

I could just go and use readxl package's functions such as read_xls or read_xlsx,which would replace the empty strings with NA

But I would like to know if there is a way if I can replace the empty strings after loading into R in the dataframe.

I tried this way but it throws up error, which I don't exactly understand.
I can specify NA in 'NA' in the below code then it would replace with NA but that would be string (NA) not missing value NA, both would be different.

```
titanic %>% mutate(boat = if_else(boat=="", NA ,boat))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: `false` must be type logical, not character.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By specifying just `NA`, according to `?NA` -"NA is a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing value."

The `class` can be checked

```
class(NA)
#[1] "logical"
class(NA_character_) 
#[1] "character"
```

and both of them is identified by standard functions such as `is.na`

```
is.na(NA)
#[1] TRUE
is.na(NA_character_)
#[1] TRUE
```

The `if_else` is type sensitive, so instead of specifying as `NA` which returns a logical output, it can specified as either `NA_real_`, `NA_integer_`, `NA_character_` depending on the type of the 'boat' column.  Assuming that the 'boat' is `character` class, we may need `NA_character_`

```
titanic %>% 
       mutate(boat = if_else(boat=="", NA_character_ ,boat))
```

Comment: I am new to R and what you said worked. Could you please explain a little more in detail what these three are? In reality NA does not have any value then why are there three types of NA?

Comment: @shafeeqrahaman  I added more info.  You can also check `?NA`

Comment: @akrun answered the implicit question so I'll just note you can also use the last class-sensitive ifelse instead of if_else a la:
titanic %>% mutate(boat = ifelse(boat=="", NA ,boat))

Answer (score 1):

You can replace specified values with an NA using the `naniar` package  - http://naniar.njtierney.com/

```r
df <- data.frame(boat = c(1, 2, "", 3), category = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))


df
#>   boat category
#> 1    1        a
#> 2    2        b
#> 3             c
#> 4    3        d
library(naniar)

df %>% replace_with_na(replace = list(boat = ""))
#>   boat category
#> 1    1        a
#> 2    2        b
#> 3 <NA>        c
#> 4    3        d

# You can also specify how to do this for a specific, using the development
# version - devtools::install_github('njtierney/naniar')
df %>% replace_with_na_at(.vars = "boat", ~.x == "")
#>   boat category
#> 1    2        a
#> 2    3        b
#> 3   NA        c
#> 4    4        d
```

Let me know if you need any clarification!

Comment: can you explain the difference between replace_with_na and replace_with_na_at

Comment: Yup - `replace_with_na_at` allows you to specify the variables that you want to influence, and also has a different way to describe which things you want to replace with missing values (NA).

Compared to replace_with_na - for this to work you need to specify `list(variable = "value")`.

This seems a bit weird, but it is built to work with some existing functions in `tidyr` - `replace_na` - which follows the syntax with `list`, and also the special variants of `_at`, `_all`, and `_if` from the dplyr family.

Let me know if you have any questions!